# Using purrr to fit many survival models using tidymodels

Tags: r, purrr, tidymodels, r-parsnip

I am trying to fit many survival models using tidymodels, workflow, and purr.
I can get this approach to work for other models, e.g., linear regression, but not survival.
I have loaded the survival extension to parsnip.

Here is code to

1. Generate a small dataset.
2. Demonstrate that usual cox-ph works fine.
3. Run linear regression with tidymodels and workflows and it works fine (models1).
4. However, models2 and models3 result in error message:
   Error in `fit_xy()':
   !Models for censored regression must use the formula interface.

This message does not help me much. I suppose it has something to do with the in-line Surv() object but haven't been able to see how to construct this another way.

I realize that parsnip for survival may still be work-in-progress, but it is unclear to me if this has been implemented and should work or not.
Appreciate any help,
Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(survival)
library(censored)

set.seed(1973)
df <- tibble(id = seq(1:1000))
df <- df %>% mutate( survtime = floor(100*rgamma(n=1000, shape =1 , rate=1)) ,
                     fail = runif(n=1000) >0.33 ,
                      a1 = runif(n=1000) >0.1,
                     a2 = runif(n=1000) >0.5)
                     

head(df)

cox1 <- coxph(data = df, Surv(survtime, event=fail) ~a1)
summary(cox1)

cox2 <- coxph(data = df, Surv(survtime, event=fail) ~a2)
summary(cox2)

A <- c("a1", "a2")
models1 <- map(A,
               ~workflow() %>%
                 add_model(linear_reg()) %>%
                 add_formula(reformulate(.x, response = 'survtime')) %>%
                 fit(df)
)
models1

#not working
models2 <- map(A,
               ~workflow() %>%
                 add_model(proportional_hazards()) %>%
                 add_formula(reformulate(.x, response = 'Surv(survtime, event=fail)')) %>%
                 fit(df)
)


#not working
models3 <- map(A,
               ~workflow() %>%
                 add_model(proportional_hazards()) %>%
                 add_formula(as.formula(paste0('Surv(survtime, event=fail) ~ ', .x))) %>%
                 fit(df)
)
models3
```

EDITED to change variables X, x1, and x2 to A, a1, and a2 for clarity.
Error message is the same:

Error in `fit_xy()':
!Models for censored regression must use the formula interface.

However, problem may be version of R or packages.
Error happens with version 4.1.2 with
survival 3.4-0
parsnip 1.0.1

but code works on another system with
R 4.2.2
parsnip 1.0.3
survival 3.3-1

Unfortunately, I am at sysadmin's mercy for updates so I did not check versioning and cannot easily troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

Uppercase "X" instead of lower case "x" is the issue.

Your not the first to do this (I stared at it for a few minutes to see it) so don't feel bad.

However... this example is exactly why we have the [`reprex`](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) package. That would have told you the issue right away since it starts with a fresh session (and would show us the error message)

Knowing's half the battle :-)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(survival)
library(censored)

set.seed(1973)
df <- tibble(id = seq(1:1000))
df <- df %>% mutate( survtime = floor(100*rgamma(n=1000, shape =1 , rate=1)) ,
                     fail = runif(n=1000) >0.33 ,
                      x1 = runif(n=1000) >0.1,
                     x2 = runif(n=1000) >0.5)
                     

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>      id survtime fail  x1    x2   
#>   <int>    <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1       27 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 2     2       77 FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
#> 3     3      180 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 4     4      127 FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
#> 5     5       69 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
#> 6     6       20 FALSE TRUE  TRUE

cox1 <- coxph(data = df, Surv(survtime, event=fail) ~x1)
summary(cox1)
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(survtime, event = fail) ~ x1, data = df)
#> 
#>   n= 1000, number of events= 692 
#> 
#>          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
#> x1TRUE 0.2854    1.3303   0.1250 2.284   0.0224 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#>        exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
#> x1TRUE      1.33     0.7517     1.041     1.699
#> 
#> Concordance= 0.509  (se = 0.007 )
#> Likelihood ratio test= 5.62  on 1 df,   p=0.02
#> Wald test            = 5.22  on 1 df,   p=0.02
#> Score (logrank) test = 5.25  on 1 df,   p=0.02

cox2 <- coxph(data = df, Surv(survtime, event=fail) ~x2)
summary(cox2)
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(survtime, event = fail) ~ x2, data = df)
#> 
#>   n= 1000, number of events= 692 
#> 
#>           coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
#> x2TRUE 0.13210   1.14122  0.07655 1.726   0.0844 .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#>        exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
#> x2TRUE     1.141     0.8763    0.9822     1.326
#> 
#> Concordance= 0.513  (se = 0.011 )
#> Likelihood ratio test= 2.98  on 1 df,   p=0.08
#> Wald test            = 2.98  on 1 df,   p=0.08
#> Score (logrank) test = 2.98  on 1 df,   p=0.08

X <- c("x1", "x2")
models1 <- map(X,
               ~workflow() %>%
                 add_model(linear_reg()) %>%
                 add_formula(reformulate(.x, response = 'survtime')) %>%
                 fit(df)
)
models1
#> [[1]]
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: linear_reg()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> survtime ~ x1
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats::lm(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       x1TRUE  
#>      121.24       -23.58  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: linear_reg()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> survtime ~ x2
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats::lm(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       x2TRUE  
#>     104.055       -7.706

#not working
models2 <- map(x,
               ~workflow() %>%
                 add_model(proportional_hazards()) %>%
                 add_formula(reformulate(.x, response = 'Surv(survtime, event=fail)')) %>%
                 fit(df)
)
#> Error in vctrs_vec_compat(.x, .purrr_user_env): object 'x' not found


#not working
models3 <- map(x,
               ~workflow() %>%
                 add_model(proportional_hazards()) %>%
                 add_formula(as.formula(paste0('Surv(survtime, event=fail) ~ ', .x))) %>%
                 fit(df)
)
#> Error in vctrs_vec_compat(.x, .purrr_user_env): object 'x' not found
models3
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'models3' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Although an issue with the posted code, it was not the issue on my actual code. (I am forced to work on a remote server without internet or copy-paste to local machine and just made a typo in beautifying the code for posting.) However problem appears to be versioning of R as noted in edit.